# Neo4j Coactor network along with movie count among coactors in the network

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I would like to create a simple coactor network (movie database from neo4j) which returns the coactors name and the movie count **among coactors as degree**. I am trying to achieve it with two queries

```
First query

MATCH (a:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves'})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coactor) RETURN a.name,coactor.name,count(movie) as degree ORDER BY degree DESC

Output from first query

+----------------+----------------------+--------+
|     a.name     |     coactor.name     | degree |
+----------------+----------------------+--------+
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Hugo Weaving"       |      3 |
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Laurence Fishburne" |      3 |
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Carrie-Anne Moss"   |      3 |
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Diane Keaton"       |      1 |
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Jack Nicholson"     |      1 |
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Brooke Langton"     |      1 |
+----------------+----------------------+--------+

Second query
    MATCH (a1:Person {name:'Hugo Weaving'})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a2:Person {name:'Laurence Fishburne'}) RETURN a1.name,a2.name,count(movie) as degree ORDER BY degree DESC

Output from second query
    +----------------+----------------------+--------+
    |    a1.name     |       a2.name        | degree |
    +----------------+----------------------+--------+
    | "Hugo Weaving" | "Laurence Fishburne" |      3 |
    +----------------+----------------------+--------+
```

I would like to perform the second query **for all the coactors** which I get from the first query.

My idea would be is to have a list of coactors and get the movie count for each pair of coactors by repeating the second query in a loop and append the result to the first query output?

Is there any other efficient way of doing this? Is there any way i can get all in a single query? or am I doing something terribly wrong here.

Expected Result

Output from first query + Output from second query

```
+----------------+----------------------+--------+
|     a.name     |     coactor.name     | degree |
+----------------+----------------------+--------+
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Hugo Weaving"       |      3 |
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Laurence Fishburne" |      3 |
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Carrie-Anne Moss"   |      3 |
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Diane Keaton"       |      1 |
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Jack Nicholson"     |      1 |
| "Keanu Reeves" | "Brooke Langton"     |      1 |
| "Hugo Weaving" | "Laurence Fishburne" |      3 |
| Carrie-Anne Moss| Laurence Fishburne  |      ? |
+----------------+----------------------+--------+
```

Any insights in the right direction is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
MATCH (k:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves'})-[:ACTED_IN*2]-(coactor)
WITH k + collect(DISTINCT coactor) as coactors
UNWIND coactors as actor
MATCH (actor)-[:ACTED_IN*2]-(coactor)
WHERE coactor IN coactors
WITH actor, coactor, count(*) as degree
ORDER BY degree DESC
RETURN actor.name, coactor.name, degree
```

We need to first gather Keanu Reeves and all his coactors, then address them all as a single variable and only match out to coactors who are in that set.

Keep in mind the results here include mirrored results (so you'll have `"Keanu Reeves" "Carrie-Anne Moss"` on one line and `"Carrie-Anne Moss" "Keanu Reeves"` on another). If you want to fix that, you'll need to add a predicate on your WHERE clause applying some kind of restriction, like `AND actor.name < coactor.name` or `AND id(actor) < id(coactor)`

Comment: I have added the predicate ```AND id(actor) < id(coactor)``` and the query works like a charm without the mirrored results. Thank you.